# Is there a term for a marriage between a Catholic and a Protestant?

Tags: terminology, marriage

I know that different denominations have different rules about inter-denominational marriages. Is there a specific term for this kind of marriage?

I'm looking for any term from anywhere. Best case, I'm looking for a term for a marriage specifically between a Catholic and a Protestant. Other similar terms would be acceptable, such as a marriage between a Catholic and non-Catholic, or Christian and non-Christian.

Comment: Where have you looked? You're likely to find something with a bit of searching.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Basically, it's a form of [interfaith marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaith_marriage), formerly called "mixed marriages." But this is really a question about language rather than about Christianity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basically a language question, not a question about Christianity.

Comment: I already did searches and was not able to find what I was looking for. Also, this is a question specifically about ecclesiastical terminology, not a general language question. I was hoping there might be a term in Latin used by the Catholic church.

Comment: What did you search? That might give us a clue about why you're not finding anything.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed, there _is_ a specific term used in Catholic Canon Law: a mixed marriage.  http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P41.HTM

Comment: I think that the question should stand but be radically altered in order to bring out more research. For example: What are the three types of mixed marriages recognized under canon law?

Comment: A cathestant? A protescat? A stantlic? (Just kidding!) Don

Answer (score 4):

In Catholic Canon Law, there is a term that applies: [a mixed marriage.](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P41.HTM)

A mixed marriage is one in which one person is a Catholic and the other has been baptized into another Christian denomination.  This isn't specific to Protestants, of course, it applies to any non-Catholic Christian denomination.

Comment: Well, with the possible exception of the Orthodox, a non-Catholic Christian **is** Protestant, rather by definition.

Comment: Catholics are not in full communion with the Orthodox  and as such they are not Catholic  in the terminology of canon law. The term mixed marriages applies to both protestant and Orthodox with a Catholic spouse.

Comment: And not only to Eastern Orthodox but to Oriental Orthodox as well.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There's many more besides protestant. There are multiple Orthodox churches,  including Eastern and Oriental. Also some would consider Anglican as distinct from Protestantism. One is not Protestant just because they are not Catholic, not by a long shot, not by any correct definition.

Comment: Well, no; the Orthodox are not Protestant [back to my original comment] but everything which stems from the Reformation is. Perhaps the UK is slightly odd in that we have non-conformists as well, which include Catholics.